# Do we need to get objects from db to create/update related data?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, many-to-many

There is an article about [how to update related data with the Entity Framework in an ASP.NET MVC application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/updating-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application). It implements a simple University in which you can choose your courses as an instructor.

Here is simplified version for its courses controllers:

```
private void UpdateInstructorCourses(string[] selectedCourses, Instructor instructorToUpdate)
{
   if (selectedCourses == null)
   {
      instructorToUpdate.Courses = new List<Course>();
      return;
   }

   var selectedCoursesHS = new HashSet<string>(selectedCourses);
   var instructorCourses = new HashSet<int>
       (instructorToUpdate.Courses.Select(c => c.CourseID));
   foreach (var course in db.Courses)
   {
      if (selectedCoursesHS.Contains(course.CourseID.ToString()))
      {
         if (!instructorCourses.Contains(course.CourseID))
         {
            instructorToUpdate.Courses.Add(course);
         }
      }
      else
      {
         if (instructorCourses.Contains(course.CourseID))
         {
            instructorToUpdate.Courses.Remove(course);
         }
      }
   }
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(int? id, string[] selectedCourses)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    var instructorToUpdate = db.Instructors
       .Include(i => i.Courses)
       .Where(i => i.ID == id)
       .Single();

    if (TryUpdateModel(instructorToUpdate, "",
       new string[] { "LastName", "FirstMidName", "HireDate", "OfficeAssignment" }))
    {
        try
        {
            UpdateInstructorCourses(selectedCourses, instructorToUpdate);

            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Log the error
        }
    }
    PopulateAssignedCourseData(instructorToUpdate);
    return View(instructorToUpdate);
}
```

As you can see `UpdateInstructorCourses` fills `instructorToUpdate.Courses` with objects retrieved from `db.Courses` based on `selectedCourses` which is a string array.

So, is it the only way to create many-to-many relationships? Do we need to get objects from `db` and then `Add` them to our List member? Isn't it better to only pass related object's Id and update related data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for many-to-many mappings, there are two ways to do it in EF:

1) Two `ICollection` properties (which you are already using):

```
public class Instructor
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}
public class Course
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Instructor> Instructors { get; set; }
}
```

In this case, EF will generate/use a mapping table, such as:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Instructors]([Id])
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Courses]([Id])
CREATE TABLE [dbp].[Instructor_Courses_Mapping]([Id],[InstructorId],[CoursesId])
```

Now, as you pointed out, there's no way to get a list from that mapping table, making you load the collection into memory using a navigation property. So:

2) However, you can override EF's mapping-table generation with your own custom mapping entity:

```
public class Instructor
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<InstructorCourse> InstructorCourses { get; set; }
}
public class Course
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<InstructorCourse> InstructorCourses { get; set; }
}
public class InstructorCourse
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }

    public Int32 InstructorId { get; set; }
    public Instructor Instructor { get; set; }

    public Int32 CourseId { get; set; }
    public Course Course { get; set; }
}
```

Now, EF will generate these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Instructors]([Id])
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Courses]([Id])
CREATE TABLE [dbp].[InstructorCourses]([Id],[InstructorId],[CourseId])
```

This will allow you to then query for `InstructorCourses` using a dbContext:

```
var instructorCourses = dbContext.Set<InstructorCourse>().Where( c => c.InstructorId == instructorId ).ToList()
```

That will return you a list of `InstructorCourse` objects, with all `InstructorId` values matching the one your looking for. Then, if you wanted to add/remove mappings:

```
//add item
dbContext.Set<InstructorCourse>().Add(new InstructorCourse() 
{ 
    InstructorId = instructorId, 
    CourseId = courseId 
});
dbContext.SaveChanges();
//remove item
var itemToRemove = dbContext.Set<InstructorCourse>().FirstOrDefault( c => c.InstructorId == instructorId && c.CourseId == courseId);
dbContext.Set<InstructorCourse>().Remove(itemToRemove);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

I found this method to be much more cleaner, represents your database structure more clearer, but it does make nested Linq statements more complicated, and nulls (without proper foreign key restrictions) potentially more common.

Comment: Great. Is there any way to introduce `InstructorCourse` by using something like Fluent API so we don't need additional models?

Comment: @Mowji No, I don't know of an alternative method. The only other option would be to manually insert/delete from the mapping table using raw sql (which obviously has it's own negatives).